# Return a table or data set from mysql stored procedure and access in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, dataset

I want to create a my sql stored procedure with start and end dates as parameters.Based on the  start and end dates,procedure should query for each day in between start and end dates.And return the result table or dataset.How to get dataset or table as result set in asp.net c#?
Please help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: Have you searched or tried something before? What you ask is a complete solution. This is a bit too broad to be considered a real question

Comment: @Steve Can you give me an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [MySqlDataAdapter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html)

> Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are
>   used to fill a dataset and update a MySQL database

Example from the Article:

```
public DataSet SelectRows(DataSet dataset,string connection,string query) 
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}
```

Where `SelectCommand` could be a select query or Stored Procedure

> Parameters: MySqlCommand that is a SQL SELECT statement or stored
>   procedure and is set as the SelectCommand property of the
>   MySqlDataAdapter.